# how to install SFGUI and SFML visual Studio

Tags: c++, sfml

I trying install SFML and SFGUI on Visual Studio 2010, but i can't install. 
I used Cmake, but it don't work. With SFML,I install by link to library, SFGUI don't work.

Help me!

How to install SFML and SFGUI using Visual Studio 2010 with images???

Comment: Keep in mind that the latest changes to SFGUI broke intentionally comparability with VS 2010 and 2012, since they've moved on with C++11 features these two compilers do not support.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good [guide at the SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-vc.php) page. Make sure you follow it to the letter. It's very important you read it first, don't skip steps and download the correct files. For 2010 there should be no need to use CMake. At the time of this post, you only need to build yourself for VS2013.

Current (at the time of this post) guides to SFGUI can be found [here](http://sfgui.sfml-dev.de/p/docs/guide). Please note that due to the use of C++11 features, only VS2013 is supported. You can download VS2013 Express for free on the Microsoft site.

That means if you want to use both SFML and SFGUI, you have to use VS2013 and rebuild SFML from scratch. That's easy, *if* you follow the instructions carefully. If something fails, reread the instructions.

Comment: You left out SFGUI... ;)